# Use of pipe | in oozie action

Tags: shell, oozie

I want to do some simple thing like

```
echo 'my text' | grep my
```

in oozie shell action.

oozie does not seem to be able to handle the `|` as an argument.

Has any one been able to get a `|` working inside oozie?

Comment: Does this produce an error ?If so what does it say ?

Comment: it executes the first part before the | and quits. in some combinations of | and scripts, it says illegal arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around Oozie's limited shell functions with a wrapper Shell in a workflow like this:

```
<action name="shell-node-pipe">
  <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <exec>bash</exec>
    <argument>-c</argument>
    <argument>/bin/echo my test | grep my</argument>
    <capture-output />
  </shell>
  <ok to="end" />
  <error to="fail" />
</action>
```

This way, the "-c" option of bash is utilized to invoke a command which contains a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

With the example given, you can work around a pipe like this

```
grep my <<< 'my text'
```

[§ Useless use of cat](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: not looking for help how to rewrite shell scripts. I tried all different ways to get around the pipe myself. oozie simply can not accept anything more than a simple command followed by arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I looked deep into oozie. It auto generates a wrapper to execute the commands you enter, and apparently the wrapper can not handle anything except a simple command with arguments.